# IMethodBinding getFullyQualifiedName if method is a method in an anonymous class

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I use the following code to get the fully qualified name of a method:

```
private void extractDataFromMethodBinding(IMethodBinding binding) {
    if (binding != null) {
        ITypeBinding type = binding.getDeclaringClass();
        if (type != null) {
            return type.getQualifiedName();
        } else {
            return "?.";
        }
}
```

This works fine for normal methods, but when I have a method inside an anonyomous class, it just resturns `.methodName()`;

I would prefer `ClassName.?.methodName()`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: correct the return type in the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to check if the declaring class of the method is the anonymous class (or nested, local, annotation, etc., if any);
2. If it is true you need to get the declaring class of the anonymous class and build return string specifying fully qualified name of the class and adding ".?." or whatever you want as the anonymous class name.

So, your code should look like this:

```
private String extractDataFromMethodBinding(IMethodBinding binding) {
    if (binding != null) {
        ITypeBinding type = binding.getDeclaringClass();
        if (type != null) {
             if( type.isAnonymous()){
                 return type.getDeclaringClass().getQualifiedName()+".?."; 
             }
            return type.getQualifiedName();
        } else {
            return "?.";
        }
    }
}
```